# Mock function doesn't intimate the behaviors of Object models

Tags: java, testing, junit, model, mockito

I write junit test for check exception handling. At first, I mock BillItems objects models as I think it will intimate the behaviors of objects models. However, when I run the test I find out that there are some different between the behaviors of mock and real objects models.

**My Objects Models**

```
public class BillItems implements Serializable {

    private MenuItem menuItem;
    private int quantity;
    private String orderTime;


    public BillItems(){}
    public BillItems(MenuItem menuItem,int quantity,String orderTime){
        this.menuItem = menuItem;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.orderTime = orderTime;
    }

    public MenuItem getMenuItem() {
        return menuItem;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        this.menuItem = menuItem;
    }

    public String getOrderTime() {
        return orderTime;
    }

    public void setOrderTime(String orderTime) {
        this.orderTime = orderTime;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        if(quantity<0){   //here it will throw the exception
            throw new IllegalStateException("Bill item cannot smaller than 0 !!!");
        }else {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

**My Junit test with mock method**

```
@Test
    public void whenAddNewMenuItemsToBill_throwIllegalStateException_ifQuantityIsSmallerThanZero(){
        DailyMenu dailyMenu = mock(DailyMenu.class);
        BillItems billItems = mock(BillItems.class); // Here is problem
        MenuItem menuItem =  mock(MenuItem.class);
        List<BillItems> billItemsList = mock(ArrayList.class);

        menuPrinter.printMenu(dailyMenu);
        verify(menuPrinter).printMenu(dailyMenu);

        billItems.setMenuItem(menuItem);

        IllegalStateException exception = assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class,()->{
            billItems.setQuantity(-4);
        });
        assertTrue(exception.getMessage().contains("Bill item cannot smaller than 0 !!!"));
    }
```

**The error:**

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.IllegalStateException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3083)
    at tests.bill.BillItemTest.whenAddNewMenuItemsToBill_throwIllegalStateException_ifQuantityIsSmallerThanZero(BillItemTest.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

When I change the Bill Items mock to models the problem was fixed:

```
 @Test
    public void whenAddNewMenuItemsToBill_throwIllegalStateException_ifQuantityIsSmallerThanZero(){
        DailyMenu dailyMenu = mock(DailyMenu.class);
        BillItems billItems = new BillItems(); // I change here
        MenuItem menuItem =  mock(MenuItem.class);
        List<BillItems> billItemsList = mock(ArrayList.class);

        menuPrinter.printMenu(dailyMenu);
        verify(menuPrinter).printMenu(dailyMenu);

        billItems.setMenuItem(menuItem);

        IllegalStateException exception = assertThrows(IllegalStateException.class,()->{
            billItems.setQuantity(-4);
        });
        assertTrue(exception.getMessage().contains("Bill item cannot smaller than 0 !!!"));
    }
```

And the test passed with no errors !!!

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Are there any reason for this issues? I am beginner with writing Junit test. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Why would you want to mock the class under test? Class under test shouldn't be mocked dependencies of the class under test can be mocked

Comment: Also when you mock you've to provide the mocked object with how to behave by mocking methods, since you've not mocked the method `billItems.setQuantity();` it bound to happen

Comment: What do you mean with "the mock's behavior is different from the real behavior"? Of course it is, that's the whole point of a mock. It's a completely detached (in theory) implementation of your type, only sharing the names of the public methods. Without setup, the methods in a mock do nothing at all.